# How to check if an image has DCI-P3 color space from a nodejs web application?

Tags: node.js, color-space

Recently I was working with a node app where I needed to upload images, the image upload is working fine but I got an issue with the uploaded images. If any of the image has DCI-P3 color space in it, I was getting some error where I was showing the images. So I decided to restrict users from uploading images with DCI-P3 color space. Now  I am facing problem how to check if an image has this DCI-P3 color space from my node application

Comment: Which image format? The image format decides if and how to store colour space. Note: often you will see no std colour space, but a user specific one.  In general, you should accept all colour spaces, an hoping users will get programs that understand ICC and so correctly display images.

Comment: It's happening for png, jgp, jpeg for my case but I think it is not related to image format.

Comment: It depends. I do no know high level libraries, but probably there are some about ICC profiles (which give you colour space). And BTW I think the original error is how you handle profiles. The second way it is to check the colour space for few image formats. I think this last is most easy for common cases, ICC profile extensions were added later, and I'm not sure many programs write them. So.. look for libraries about getting ICC profile informations. Then when you get it, you can ask a new question: how to tell if an image is in a "very different" colour space compared sRGB.